# Why does the program take more time to execute on newer devices than old ones?

Tags: java, android, objective-c, c, iphone

I'm executing a function written in C on different smartphones. The smartphones are iPhone 6, iPhone 7, Nexus 5 and Samsung Galaxy S7.

For android I am using the following functions to get the time.

```
typedef struct Timer {
    unsigned int totalRuns;
    unsigned long long totalTime;
    struct timespec startTime;
    struct timespec stopTime;
} Timer;

Void start(Timer* timer){
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &(timer->startTime));
}

void stop(Timer* timer){
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &(timer->stopTime));
    timer->totalTime += (timer->stopTime.tv_sec - timer->startTime.tv_sec)*1000000000LL + timer->stopTime.tv_nsec - timer->startTime.tv_nsec;
    timer->totalRuns++;
}
```

And in iOS I am calling the timing functions in Objective C using the following code snippet.

```
NSDate *start, *stop;
NSTimeInterval executionTime = 0;

start = [NSDate date];
//Function to be timed
stop = [NSDate date];
executionTime = [stop timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
```

The same code timed in Nexus 5 and iPhone 6 shows faster execution times than in iPhone 7 and Samsung Galaxy S7, however I felt it should be the other way around given that the new phones are faster. What can be the reason for this discrepancy? Or is there a way to time uniformly across all 4 devices?

Comment: "What can be the reason for this discrepancy?" -- everything else about the environments.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: From a hardware standpoint, the RAM is different (amount and possibly speed), the CPUs are different (and "faster" has several parameters with CPUs), the on-board storage is different (size, speed). From a software standpoint, at least on Android, the mix of other running processes will be different, which in turn affects your app's ability to use that RAM, CPU, and on-board storage. And that's without knowing much of anything about the code that you are testing, as there could be plenty of other variables (WiFi radios, cellular radios, GPUs, etc.).

Comment: So the code I am testing is processing an audio frame. Basically it is an array of floats with some mathematical calculations. I am not accessing any device peripherals or the storage during that calculation. And all that is using pointer arrays. The calculations involve calculating the FFT of the frame, extracting some features and doing some predictions.

Comment: Perhaps the floating-point support in the newer CPUs is weaker in comparison to the older ones. Perhaps, on Android, Samsung's extra apps are interrupting your tests and stealing CPU time. Perhaps your code is multi-threaded and the CPU scheduling is different between the versions, harming your benchmark. Perhaps the RAM access speed on the newer devices is slower. And so on.

Comment: I'll look into these points. Thank you @CommonsWare.